# How src of img should look like

Tags: html, image, jboss5.x, src

How do I display an image which is located outside the context root.

i.e the image is located in `<jboss_root_folder>/images/myImage.jpg` .

How the `src` of `img` tag should look like in such case?

Any lead in this regard will be of great help.

The below line works in a html file : `<img src="file:///G:/DevEnv/jboss-5.1.0.GA/images/DSCN0968.jpg">` where as the same line from my xhtml does not work when accessed from server

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 0):

You can either give the full url i.e. `http://www.example.com/root/images/myImage.jpg` or use relative paths i.e. if root is two levels down from the page location: `../../image/myImage.jpg`. For an example, see [this page](http://www.chami.com/html-kit/minit/pages/imgtag1.html).

Comment: oh i hate using the relative path in this case since I can get complete path of the image like `c:\jboss\images\myImage.jpg` . Can I use that complete path in `img` tag?

Comment: Also I could have used a servlet to stream the image file, but that will be last option for me. So hoping for any other easy way...

Comment: You can't use a file path local to your machine (like C:\etc or file:///), it won't work once you are online since those drive letters become meaningless. Your best bet for both online and offline testing is to use relative paths.